# Always have to chown when adding new file? Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6, chown, ownership

Whenever I upload a new file to my server, I have to `chown -R apache:apache /dir` in order for it to be accessible.

Is there an easier way around this?

Comment: Is this your own server? Then we need to know what ftp-server you are running. In every ftp server you can change the configuration so that uploaded files get the right user:group and permissions. It is also possible to work with inherited permission from the parent directory or with ACL (Access Control List) but it is far easier to set it in the ftp-server.

Comment: Unless you're FTPing into your server as the user `apache:apache` then yes, you need to do this, be it manually or via some sort of FTP client/server config

Comment: @Jobbo How might I go upon uploading as the user apache:apache?

Comment: @Travis You could login to ftp with username `apache` (if you've got a password for that). Otherwise you need to change the config of your ftp-server. Is this your own server? And what server-daemon are you running? VSFTPD or something else?

Comment: @Rik I am using vsftpd   This is also my server. I have root access and I have been uploading everything as root.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, what is actually needed for the files to be accessible is that their group is set to `apache`. You can easily set it by default for new created files by running :

```
find /path/to/root/directory/of/website -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s
```

This will set the `setgid` flag on all sub-directories too. With this flag set, any new file created in there will inherit the group of its parent directory. (`-print0` and `-0` options are designed to handle correctly spaces in filenames)

Make sure ownerships of files are correct before running it. If unsure, you can fix it the same way :

```
find /path/to/root/directory/of/website -print0 | xargs -0 chown apache:apache
```

Comment: And what about a new **directory** he creates with the ftp-program?

Comment: They should inherit as well, as long as the ftp-program does not explicitly changes the group.

Comment: Yeah, that works. I think i was confused with "user"-part. That can't be inherited without using ACLs. But just for the group part the `setgid` works fine (+1). If the ftp-program does set the group... well... then there is nothing else to do then change its configuration. I did just test it with VSFTPD and with that it works. (The group is not set to the one defined in the vsftpd.conf but takes it from its parent directory)

Comment: @Levans when I run that command I issue 'find /var/www/travisingram.net/public_html -type d | xargs chmod g+s' and the permissions aren't affected. Another way I know of that it has not changed is in WordPress, whenever I update/install a plugin it'll require FTP or SFTP. Now, if its been chown with apache:apache I shouldn't se that. Did I not do the command correctly? I am running vsftpd

Comment: @Travis are you running this command with sufficient rights (as `root` user) ? When displaying the file permissions (with `ls -l`), you should see an `S` instead of the `x` for group permissions on directories.

Comment: @Travis With this method you are setting the directory `setgid`s. So this would only work for **new** files (**not** for existing **files**). It also expects you already `chown`ed the directories (and files) to `apache:apache`. So if all your files/directories are `apache:apache` **then** run this command and it will be fine for all future files/directories.

Comment: @Levans I think your command will likely fail with directory-names with spaces. Maybe you could use `find /path/to/root/directory/of/website -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s`. (Note the `-print0` and `-0`). Also, you might want to add a command to first `chown` all files to `apache:apache`. Like `find /path/to/root/directory/of/website -print0 | xargs -0 chown apache:apache`. that way you're sure they are all the right user:group.

Comment: @Rik indeed, I forgot the spaces problem and assumed he already fixed ownership manually. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @Levans so I ran the commands you instructed, and in fact things are working better then what they use to be. I uploaded a new file after I did all the commands and it shows up as 0/48. http://puu.sh/5AlKu.png Do you think if it showed a 0 that might affect anything?

Comment: @Travis this means that the ownership of this file is `root:apache`, as long as I know, apache needs at least the `group` part to access the file, so it should be okay.

Comment: @Travis This should be fine. But i still wouldn't use root for uploading. The file doesn't have execute rights in this case but it is not advised to make root the owner. Just login to ftp with your normal username and password and it should all work fine. (I take it you do have normal user accounts on this machine)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do with VSFTPD:

You can set the following 2 options in you `vsftpd.conf`:

```
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=apache
```

`guest_enable`, if enabled, makes sure **all** files are uploaded as user/group `apache`.

Please note that this will only work for files uploaded via FTP. If you copy a file in Linux itself to your www directory, **this will not adjust the permissions**.

---

That's why, if you're also accessing that directory via the filesystem, it is best to use the `chmod g+s`-method Levans suggested.
(i.e.)

```
find /var/www/site/public_html -print0 | xargs -0 chown apache:apache
find /var/www/site/public_html -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s
```

---

> **guest_enable**
>   If enabled, all non-anonymous logins are classed as "guest" logins. A guest login is remapped to the user specified in the guest_username setting.
>
> Default: **NO**
>
> **guest_username**
>   See the boolean setting guest_enable for a description of what constitutes a guest login. This setting is the real username which guest users are mapped to.
>
> Default: **ftp**

Comment: Would apache have the same password as root? Guess not, decided to give it a go before I asked. So is it without password open for general use? Sorta confused here.

Comment: You shouldn't use root to login to ftp. There is a username ftp setup for it. But it doesn't matter with what user you login (you can setup ftp users in the config), you need to tell the ftp-program to write the files as `apache:apache` because your webserver needs access. (Even if user apache has no password/ftp access the files can still be written with that user as long as vsftpd assigns it to that user. That's where these lines are for)

Comment: And only if you enabled anonymous, anyone could login without a password. If it's disabled you can login with the users you have enabled access for ftp. This could be from standard Linux used to a simple login.txt where you defined users and passwords. That depends on your config file. `guest_enabled` is a bit confusing because it has nothing to do with 'guest'-access but makes vsftpd write a different user (remap) for 'normal' users.

Comment: how might I go upon setting passwords for it then? I do not know the specific commands for vsftpd.

Comment: Seen you post on that other question I made earlier. I forgot about making a question previous. I found that I had this one actually after I created that one. Anyways, I just removed it.

Comment: If you have a standard setup of vsftpd you should be able to login with your normal username. Did you try that? And with the lines above (`guest_xxx`) all uploaded files will be `chown`ed to `apache`. If logging in as a normal user doesn't work we need to see your complete `vsftpd.conf` to advise you.

Comment: Rik how might I set a password for this guest_xxx user though?

Comment: @Travis you misunderstand. `guest_username` and `guest_enabled` are settings. You should set `guest_username` to `apache` and `guest_enable` to `yes`. After that you can just login as the user you created with the install of CentOS (with the correct password) and it will be saved as user `apache` (which you wanted). Normally it is discouraged to use `root` for this. You **do have** a normal user account on that machine, don't you?